# Get Github File Contents By Git Oauth Token

Tags: github

I am following these documentation

https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-repository-content

I was able to create an oAuth token

```
access_token=gho_zKoEO1cv****************05&scope=repo&token_type=bearer
```

On all my requests I am passing the token in header Authorization: token

To confirm my token is working, i used

```
https://api.github.com/user
```

and i get 200 success response, and all my datas are listed.

I have a private repo and confirmed its file location by raw url

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<myusername>/<myrepo>/master/<myfile>.txt?token=<token_generated_by_github_when_raw_clicked>
```

Referring to the doucmentation, i need to use api.github.com to get the file contents

I tried below combinations

```
https://api.github.com/repos/<myusername>/<myrepo>/contents/<myfile>.txt
https://api.github.com/repos/<myusername>/<myrepo>/contents/master/<myfile>.txt
```

But i am getting a message Not Found

[image]

It would be helpful if someone guide what i am missing on the url

I even tried with raw url,

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<myusername>/<myrepo>/master/<myfile>.txt
```

but getting 404...

**Update 1**

```
https://api.github.com/repos/<myusername>/<myrepo>/contents/
```

returns

```
{
    "message": "Not Found",
    "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#get-repository-content"
}
```

In case below helps

```
https://api.github.com/user/repos
```

lists down all my public repos. Not any private repo.

**Answer**

My mistake... I was testing on postman different tab. And only on the tab to fetch content, i missed the word token in Authorization header. It is working fine now.

Comment: You can see all the files in the repo by `https://api.github.com/repos/<myusername>/<myrepo>/contents/`can you confirm whether your file is listed or not?

Comment: @Zeromika I have updated the question. No, it is not listed.